# Epimorphisms of magmas: are they surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Is any epimorphism in the category of magmas surjective? More generally, is the same statement true for the category of sets with an $I$-ary operation, where $I$ is any (possibly infinite) set?

A magma is just a set with any random binary operation on it. It need not be commutative, associative, have an identity, have inverses, etc.